# Is it any way to customize the QLPreviewPanel's buttons at its top right corner in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

As you can see, the system has a way to show different controller set for different file type.

[image]

[image]

I'd like to do the same thing in my macOS App. At the moment, I can pragmatically open a QLPreviewPanel to show a temp image file. But I don't know how to add a "Copy" button at the top right corner.

Currently, I have code like this:

```
//...
let panel = MyQLViewController()
panel.previewFile(self, url: url)
//...

class MyQLViewController: NSViewController, QLPreviewPanelDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDelegate {
    var url: URL!
    
    @objc func previewFile(_ sender: Any, url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        if let panel = QLPreviewPanel.shared() {
            panel.dataSource = self
            panel.delegate = self
            panel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        }
    }
    
    override func acceptsPreviewPanelControl(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func beginPreviewPanelControl(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!) {
        panel.dataSource = self
        panel.delegate = self
    }

    override func endPreviewPanelControl(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!) {
        panel.dataSource = nil
        panel.delegate = nil
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func previewPanel(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {
        return self.url as QLPreviewItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely not customize as there is bunch of work in the framework related to that button. The only hack I have in my mind (possible) is to add another button. But this is hacky as it's manipulating window hierarchy.